# Login cohort over months

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables(users,logins). I would like to create a query that pulls users who have a users create_date and a logins create_date in april. Then I would like to see how many of these users have a login create_date in may. (Login Cohort)

```
User_id | create_date

  1 | 04-05-16

  2 | 04-08-16

  3 | 05-05-16

  4 | 05-06-16

User_id | login_create_date

  1 | 04-05-16

  1 | 05-08-16

  1 | 05-09-16

  2 | 04-09-16

  2 | 05-015-16

  3 | 05-16-16

  3 | 05-20-16

  3 | 05-21-16
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method using `exists`:

```
select count(*) as April_Creates,
       sum(case when exists (select 1
                             from logins l2
                             where l2.user_id = u.user_id and
                                   l2.create_date >= '2016-05-01' and l2.create_date < '2016-06-01'
                            )
                 then 1 else 0
           end) as May_Logins
from users u
where u.create_date >= '2016-04-01' and u.create_date < '2016-05-01' and
      exists (select 1
              from logins l
              where l.user_id = u.user_id and
                    l.create_date >= '2016-04-01' and l.create_date < '2016-05-01'
             );
```

An alternative method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(apr_login) as num_apr_logins,
       sum(may_login) as num_may_logins,
       sum(may_login) / 1.0 * sum(may_login) as ratio
from users u join
     (select user_id,
             max(case when l.create_date >= '2016-04-01' and l.create_date < '2016-05-01'
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) as apr_login,
             max(case when l.create_date >= '2016-05-01' and l.create_date < '2016-06-01'
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) as may_login
      from logins l
      group by user_id
      having apr_login = 1
     ) l
where u.create_date >= '2016-04-01' and u.create_date < '2016-05-01' ;
```

Comment: Sorry I should also add that the records in the users table are unique, but the user can have many instances in the logins table. Using your first method, how would I ensure that we are only counting users once?

Comment: @Cletus . . . The first query only selects from the `users` table, so there can be no duplicate users.

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of using left join and conditional aggregation rather than sub/nested selects for this case...

```
SELECT
    u.[User_id]
    ,u.create_date
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM l.login_create_date) = 4 THEN 1 END) as AprilLoginsCreated
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM l.login_create_date) = 5 THEN 1 END) as MayLoginsCreated
FROM
    users u
    LEFT JOIN logins l
    ON u.[User_id] = l.[User_id]
    AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM l.login_create_date) IN (4,5)
    AND l.login_create_date >= '2016-04-01'
WHERE
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM u.create_date) IN (4)
    AND u.create_date >= '2016-04-01'
GROUP BY
    u.[User_id]
    ,u.create_date
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM l.login_create_date) = 4 THEN l END) > 1
```

So stepping through the query.

- Join user table to logins but only the logins that where created in April & May
- Use a case statement in the aggregation to count the number of logins created for April & May
- use the same conditional aggregation statment for April in the having clause to reduce the records to be only those that had a user and login created in April.